# Trouble with async data in Angular JS application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am modifying an existing Angular JS application (code can be found here https://github.com/gmathiou/gtfs-manager).

In one file (trips-page-module.js) I have the following code:

```
$scope.saveTrip = function(itemToSave) {
    $scope.computeNewStoptimeSequence();
    LoadDataService.saveTrip(itemToSave)
      .then(function(data) {
        if (data["_id"] != null) {  
          $scope.tripsForRoutes.push(data);
          $scope.active_trip_item = data;
        }
      })
      .then( function (data) { 
          var dirtyElem = angular.element("ng-dirty");
          var toUpdate = [];
          for(var i = 0; i <= dirtyElem.length, i++){
             toUpdate.push(dirtyElem[i].scope().stoptime);
          } 
          LoadDataService.saveStopTimesForTrip(toUpdate);
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        $scope.editing = false;
      });
  }
```

which, basically, creates an array of all the elements that are dirty and have to be updated before passing it to LoadDataService.saveStopTimesForTrip. 
Still, when I run it I get that dirtyElem[i] is undefined. I clearly understand this is due to the asynchronous nature of the code. 
What I don't get is how can I fix it? How can I wait for all my async function to finish?

Comment: `dirtyElem.legth` is this typo also in the original source or only in the example-snippet?

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i , dirtyElem.legth, i++)` wtf is this? -1!

Comment: `dirtyELem` - capital `L` isn't supposed to be caps